# Getting In Container.php line 752: Class RoleTableSeeder does not exist error, when trying to seed a role in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, seed

Currently, I am trying to create roles for my application, unfortunately I am having some troubles. Whenever I run php artisan migrate --seed, I get the error I've written in the title. Honestly, I feel like I've messed up something really simple like a name but I just can't find my mistake. I'd appreciate any help.

User.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

Role.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Users table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
    }
```

Roles table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description')->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

role_user table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('role_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

RoleTableSeeder.php

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Role;

class RoleTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $role_user = new Role();
        $role_user->name = 'User';
        $role_user->description = "Normal User";
        $role_user->save();

        $role_admin = new Role();
        $role_admin->name = 'Admin';
        $role_admin->description = "Admin User";
        $role_admin->save();
    }
}
```

UserTableSeeder.php

```
public function run()
    {
        $role_admin = Role::where('name', 'Admin')->first();

        $user = new User();
        $user->first_name = 'test';
        $user->last_name = 'test';
        $user->username = 'Admin';
        $user->password = bcrypt('test');
        $user->email = 'test@gmail.com';
        $user->save();
        $user->roles()->attach($role_admin);
    }
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
public function run()
    {
        $this->call(RoleTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: post full contents of `RoleTableSeeder.php`

Comment: Done, I've added the full contents

Comment: use this command `php artisan make:seeder RoleTableSeeder` to create your seeder file, then copy your code there

Comment: or run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: It says command "dump-autoload" is not defined.

Comment: sorry my mistake `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what is supposed to happen? Typing php artisan make:seeder RoleTableSeeder does nothing since I already have the seeder. Typing composer dump-autoload gave me this message - [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
  The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not availab
  le. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error
  , at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.

Comment: first rename your previous seeder, then use `make:seeder` comand

Comment: I still get the same error saying the seeder does not exist.

Comment: could you please add your updated seeder, full file, just copy and paste here

Comment: I already have, just look the RoleTableSeeder.php in this post. It's the entire file.

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload` , try to fixed the error and then dump, it seems a class autoloading problem

Comment: I get this message after running composer dump-autoload: 

 [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
  The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not availab
  le. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error
  , at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.


dump-autoload [--no-scripts] [-o|--optimize] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu] [--no-dev]

Comment: first run `composer config -g -- disable-tls true` then the previous comment command

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. My php artisan migrate --seed worked fine after doing this. Thanks a lot. Put this as an answer so I can vote you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

Run: `composer dump-autoload`.

If `Composer\Exception\NoSslException` exception is thrown, you may need to run `composer config -g -- disable-tls true` before `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as above 
the composer command didn't do the trick.

on Laravel 5.5  I ran

```
 php artisan cache:clear
```

and then all my new created seeder classes were found

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue on PH 7.2.* with Lavarel 5.5.*

Solution very easy - use the namespace:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=Modules\{moduleName}\Database\Seeders\{className}DatabaseSeeder
```

Also here:

```
$this->call('Modules\{moduleName}\Database\Seeders\{className}TableSeeder');
```